# Inserting horizontal line to line chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I must plot 25 plots, each with its own dataset. I need to insert a horizontal line into each plot. Problem is, the coordinates cannot be hardcoded as each dataset's range varies.
I need to have the horizontal line always to be at the first value of the according dataset

This is my geom for the line that I tried (the y-axis intercept is hardcoded in this case and doesnt help).

```
+ geom_hline(yintercept=c(75,0), linetype="dotted")
```

I can grab the value (which is at the identical position in each dataset for each plot) for each line's y-intersepction with this:

```
dataset[1, 6]
```

which I could also store in a vector like this

```
coord <- dataset[1, 6]
```

But not having any success bringing this together

I tried with no luck:

```
 + geom_hline(yintercept=coord, linetype="dotted")
```

Example Code:

```
a <- c(10,40,30,22)
b <- c(1,2,3,4)

df <- data.frame(a,b)

try <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = b, y = a)) +  geom_line() +   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, NA)) + geom_hline(yintercept=c(30,0), linetype="dotted") + theme_tq()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exactly is causing you trouble. If I loop through a list of dataframes, I can set the `yintercept` of each corresponding plot without too much trouble. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Split the economics dataset as an example
datasets <- split(economics, cut(seq_len(nrow(economics)), 9))

# Loop through list of dataframes, set hline to [1, 6] (drop because tibble)
plots <- lapply(datasets, function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(date, unemploy)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(df[1, 6, drop = TRUE], 0),
               linetype = "dotted")
})

# For visualisation purposes
wrap_plots(plots)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Works perfectly  - i messed the drop = true part. Thx